# combine multiple tables with different columns in to a one table

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I have 4 tables that each contain different data and different column (header name). I want to create a new table that contains all the data AND all the columns into one new tables.
Note:  I am trying to select the records into a single result. no relations between any of the tables. each table collected data from somewhere else. I am trying to combine these tables into 1 so I can train a machine learning model. does this help? let me know if you need more information., thanks 
Thanks for any help

```
TABLE [db_ddladmin].[PS_sec_1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [session_id] [varchar](90) NULL,
    [Age] [varchar](750) NULL,
    [Religious] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Marital] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Sex] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Ethnicity] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Education] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Zipcode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Fist_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [flag] [char](10) NULL,
    [timdat] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


TABLE [db_ddladmin].[PS_sec_2](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [session_id] [varchar](90) NULL,
    [Height] [varchar](750) NULL,
    [Weight] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Body_type] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [eye] [int] NULL,
    [ear] [int] NULL,
    [nose] [int] NULL,
    [lip] [int] NULL,
    [toung] [int] NULL,
    [nippel] [int] NULL,
    [belly] [int] NULL,
    [clit] [int] NULL,
    [face] [int] NULL,
    [neck] [int] NULL,
    [shoulder] [int] NULL,
    [chest] [int] NULL,
    [back] [int] NULL,
    [ribs] [int] NULL,
    [stomach] [int] NULL,
    [arms] [int] NULL,
    [hand] [int] NULL,
    [thigh] [int] NULL,
    [calf] [int] NULL,
    [foot] [int] NULL,
    [flag] [char](10) NULL,
    [timdat] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: James, can we have some data (as text) and the schemas of these tables please?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "create a new table"?  Are you permanently altering the structure of your schemaand looking to migrate your data to the new structure?  Are you trying to duplicate your data for some reason?  Are you trying to create a view as a kind of virtual table from which you can select?  Are you just trying to select the records into a single result?  How is the data related?  What is the current data and what should the result be?  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: I updated the post. I just mentioned 2 tables (since i dont want it to be too long)

Comment: Thanks, I updated the posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CROSS JOIN** but its gonna be a wreck...I hope its what you want.

```
SELECT * from [db_ddladmin].[PS_sec_1]
CROSS JOIN [db_ddladmin].[PS_sec_2];
```

Comment: SELECT * 
INTO   tablenew 
FROM   (  to create a table

Answer (score 2):

lets assume your existing tables are table1,table2,table3,and table4  also lets assume the new table is called tablenew,

```
SELECT * 
INTO   tablenew 
FROM   (SELECT col1, 
               col2, 
               col3 
        FROM   table1 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT col1, 
               col2, 
               col3 
        FROM   table2 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT col1, 
               col2, 
               NULL AS Col3 
        FROM   table3)
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, Unfortunate, did not work. It created a new table but only with  three columns of first table.   I need a table with all the columns from all three tables. Thank you tho

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of discussion, lets assume there are two tables, tableA and tableB. I have created a sample data to illustrate the solution:

**TableA details:**

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA (ID Int, Name Varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #tableA VALUES (1,'John'),(2,'James')
```

**TableB details:**

```
CREATE TABLE #tableB (City Varchar(10), Country Varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #tableB VALUES ('Paris','France'),('NY','USA')
```

**Union Statement:**

```
select ID,Name,NULL as City,NULL as Country from #tableA
UNION ALL
select NULL as ID,NULL as Name,City,Country from #tableB
```

The union statement should give the result you are looking for, but getting there is going to take some manual work. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you meant *UNION statement* not *JOIN statement*.

Comment: Yes...I did...I have edited the answer...Thanks for pointing it out.